# How to include Python packages in docker file?

Tags: python-3.x, docker, dockerfile, python-packaging

I am trying to include an entire directory in my docker file. Here is my current Dockerfile:

```
FROM python:3

COPY requirements.txt ./

RUN pip install -r requirements.txt

ADD streaming_integration_test.py /

CMD python ./streaming_integration_test.py
```

However, after building this docker file and then running it, I get the following error:

```
     File "./streaming_integration_test.py", line 3, in <module>
    from data_streamer.file_utilities import FileUtilities
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'data_streamer'
```

Where `file_utilities.py` is part of a package and is in the directory `data_streamer` I am new to Docker, and I am not really sure what I am doing wrong. Thanks to all of those who reply in advance.

Comment: You can get a shell in the image you just built with `docker run --rm -it myimagename sh`.  Is the file `streaming_integration_test.py` where you expect it to be?

Comment: @DavidMaze How would I go about seeing if the file is where it should be? It is properly placed where I expect it to be outside of the container.

Comment: It's your image.  Often applications will use a `/app` directory inside an image but that's not a hard-and-fast rule at all.  Remember that the only things that will be in the image are things you COPY in (or ADD, but usually prefer COPY).  Once you have the debugging shell you can poke around there using normal shell commands.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
FROM python:3                               # pull filesystem    
COPY requirements.txt ./                    # copy single file
RUN pip install -r requirements.txt         # run command
ADD streaming_integration_test.py /         # add single file
CMD python ./streaming_integration_test.py  # run command on "docker run"ň
```

So either you need to also add this:

```
COPY ./data_streamer /data_streamer         # copy folder
```

which copies the folder (and its contents) into your new image layer or in `docker run` command mount the folder (on your host system) as a volume in your docker container (similar to `mount` command on unix systems):

```
# mount host folder `data_streamer` from the current directory (pwd) to `/data_streamer`
docker run --volume $(pwd)/data_streamer:/data_streamer [IMAGE_NAME]
```